# xdomain net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: angularjs, rest, http

I am writing AngularJS application and using xdomain (https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) proxy for CORS REST service.
Everything works fine and erros are handled correctly excpet one case - when proxy.html required by xdomain library is not accesible (network or server error) 
In that case I get:

```
GET https://server.test.pl:41012/proxy.html net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
  getFrame  xdomain.js:520
  (anonymous function)  xdomain.js:616
  facade.send.process   xdomain.js:446
  facade.send   xdomain.js:449
  (anonymous function)  angular.js:8521
  sendReq   angular.js:8315
  $HttpProvider.$get.serverRequest  angular.js:8049
  deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback angular.js:11520
  (anonymous function)  angular.js:11606
  $RootScopeProvider.$get.Scope.$eval   angular.js:12632
  $RootScopeProvider.$get.Scope.$digest angular.js:12444
  $RootScopeProvider.$get.Scope.$apply  angular.js:12736
  (anonymous function)  angular.js:1438
  invoke    angular.js:3940
  doBootstrap   angular.js:1436
  bootstrap angular.js:1450
  (anonymous function)  app.js:86
  trigger   angular.js:2563
  (anonymous function)  angular.js:2843
  forEach   angular.js:325
  eventHandler  angular.js:2842
```

I want to intercept this error and handle it but problem is I don't know how:

- $http catch/error promise method is not called
- httInterceptor i wrote is not invoked

How can I hadle this error?